# I can't use youtube-dl in oh-my-zsh

Tags: software-installation, pip, youtube-dl

I use these commands:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
pip3 install youtube-dl
```

An it says `youtube-dl` was installed.
But when I use it the terminal warns me:

```
zsh: command not found: youtube-dl
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you `which youtube-dl` to see if it is located on your path, or perhaps `/usr/bin/youtube-dl`?

Comment: Did `pip3` say where it installed `youtube-dl`? What's the output of `echo "$PATH"` and `find / -name '*youtube-dl*' 2>/dev/null`? You can also try other installation methods: [How can I update youtube-dl?](/q/380438/175814)

Comment: I use "which youtube-dl", terminal warn me  “youtube-dl not found”。 So i use "pip3 show youtube-dl",termal show me "pip3 show youtube-dl Name: youtube-dl Version: 2017.12.31 Summary: YouTube video downloader Home-page: github.com/rg3/youtube-dl Author: Sergey M. Author-email: dstftw@gmail.com License: Unlicense Location: /home/wagoo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages Requires: "